# Remove attribute label displaying under Layered Navigation

Tags: magento

**short** :

Attribute have many `dropdown values - v1,v2,v3,v4`

IF all Products are assigned to value "v1" of an attribute , means no products are assigned to "`v2,v3.v4`" than that Attribute label should not visible under Layered Navigation....

**Long** :

we wanted to hide one attribute value in layered navigation.

many attribute codes have same attribute value.

ex: "attribute codes `"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"` have attribute value "v1"

we are using following code to hide the attribute value "v1" in layered navigation.

but Attribute Label is still displaying in layered navigation.

if for attribute code : "a1" , attribute label is "L1" , values are `"v1", "v2","v3"`

if all products are assigned to "v1", than along with "v1" , I want to `hide "L1" in layered navigation.`

[image]

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <div class="fp1"><?php $Pro_name = $_product->getName();?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Specifications Of '."$Pro_name") ?></h2><br/><br/>


    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>  
            <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);

            /* hide abc */
            if($_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) == 'v1') {
                continue;
            }           

            /* hide no abc*/
            if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && (trim((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) != ''))
            {
                if ($_data['code'] == 'gendernew'): 
                ?>              
                <tr><th colspan="3"><?php echo $this->__('') ?></th></tr>
        <th class = "tablehead" colspan="3" > GENERAL </th>
                <?php elseif ($_data['code'] == 'productweight'): ?>
                <tr><th class = "tablehead" id="prod_dim" colspan="3"><p style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% ! important; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px ! important;" class="Product_dim">Product Dimension</p><?php echo $this->__('PRODUCT DIMENSION') ?></th></tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <?php 

if (($_data['code'] == 'brnad') || ($_data['code'] == 'age')||($_data['code'] == 'mobile_design'))

{ ?>
                    <td class="data">
                        <?php
                            $_ageValues = $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
                            $count = 1;
                        ?>
                        <?php if(is_array($_ageValues)): foreach($_ageValues as $_ageValue): ?>
                         <?php if($count > 1) { echo ","; } ?>
                            <?php echo $_ageValue; ?>
                            <?php $count++; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; 
                        else: echo $_product->getAttributeText($_data['code']);
                        endif; ?>
                    </td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getData($_data['code']), $_data['code']); ?></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>

            <?php            
            }
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>

<?php

$attribute_value = 'xyz ';
if (strlen($attribute_value) > 0)
{
   // code to display the value
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, below solution would resolve your issue:-

Please copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/em_layerednavigation/view.phtml`
template file(em_layerednavigation folder) and place it in your theme and append below code after line number 49:-

```
<?php if($this->__($_filter->getName())=='L1'&& $_filter->getItemsCount()<=1)
   continue;?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I will try and let you know about this.

Comment: i tried this code : http://pastebin.com/RZtE4vmj but it didt worked for me, seems i missing somewhere, please check code.

Comment: <?php $this__($_filter->getName())=='L1'&& $_filter->getItemsCount()<=1) continue?>

Comment: <?php if($this->__($_filter->getName())=='L1'&& $_filter->getItemsCount()<=1) continue;?>It's only for L1 Attribute

Comment: i am checking now.

Comment: Its working now for L1 attribute labels. what code i have to use if we have more attributes as like L1, L2,L3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
if(!$_filter->getItemsCount() || $_filter->getItemsCount()==1 && $_filter->getName()!='Category') continue;
```